# capistrano 3 deploy:clean old releases permission error

Tags: ubuntu, yii, amazon-ec2, file-permissions, capistrano3

I am trying to deploy my Yii application using capistrino 3. Sever is EC2 ubuntu instance which by default comes with a user ubuntu. I have added ubuntu user to group www-data and trying to deploy using capistrino 3 but in old releases these runtime files creates some problem.

```
groups ubuntu
ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip www-data video plugdev netdev

groups www-data
www-data : www-data
```

Apache server has created some files/folder as

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data ubuntu 4096 Oct 12 15:23 CSS
drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data ubuntu 4096 Oct 12 15:17 HTML
```

When i tried to deploy the new version it says,

```
DEBUG[c9d0212b]     rm: cannot remove '/var/www/html/zl/releases/20141012145437/frontend/runtime/CSS/4.5.0,24166bfe16a0cc6bd18d813b83121ef2eaf16545,1.ser': Permission denied
```

What can be a workaround? I have added user ubuntu to group www-data, but new files have owner www-data and group ubuntu. i have no idea how it reversed.

Comment: How you fix this issue?

Comment: It looks as if you added www-data to the group ubuntu, maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to add your `deploy user` in a `www-data` group by following the bellow command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data deployer_user_name
```

To check the `user new group`, follow the bellow command:

```
 groups deployer_user_name
```

After that capistrano clean up will be smooth ;)

Answer (score 0):

@NaimRajiv, your statement is right but my `deployer_user_name` is `ubuntu` and that is already added to group `www-data`

Problem was my directory generated by apache has permission 755 so if you want to remove is when deploying from user ubuntu it needs the group permission which is 775. I updated my PHP code generating dir and it worked.